# CSS prevent smaller font sizes from not centering

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center, font-size

I'm having trouble vertically centering 2 elements (svg + text). I used flexbox to center these elements, and they are perfectly centered if I do not precise any font-size. But when I put a smaller font-size on the text (0.8em instead of 1em), it creates a small space on top of the text instead of centering it. Horrible colors are to show the blue space on top of the text. Does anyone know how to fix this ?
I've already tried adding `text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;`
The parent div (blue) centers elements with flex: `display: flex; align-items: center;`

[image]

Thanks a lot
Edit: Here is a snippet, I somehow can't find how to link a file (the svg) ?

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Parent div*/

.parent {
  width: 20vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 1vw;
  background-color:skyblue;
}


/*Svg*/

.parent img {
  width: auto;
  height: 3vh;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: rosybrown;
}


/*Text*/

span {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  background-color: seagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather/96/heart-512.png"><span>Favoris</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add a reproduction snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="parent">
        <img src="img/coeur.svg">
        <span>Favoris</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

I just had to invert the `<a>` tag and `<div>` and everything is well centered.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set the line-height of the text element to the same value as your font-size. I would also not define a height for the text element (I am not sure if you are doing this or not, since you did not provide your code).

So something of the sort:

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #4169E1;
}

div.container img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #BC8F8F;
}

div.container span {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #4B565C;
  background-color: #2E8B57;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather/96/heart-512.png"/>
  <span>Favoris</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you help, I actually noticed with your answer it might be my <a> tag that breaks everything ? It works perfectly without it but I unfortunately need it